# Spider through Scrapyrt returns 0 items when scraping search page

Tags: scrapy

I created a spider that can scrape a page in an e-commerce site and gather the data on the different items.
The spider works fine with specific pages of the site (www.sitedomain/123-item-category), as well as with the search page (www.sitedomain/searchpage?controller?search=keywords+item+to+be+found).

But, when I run it through Scrapyrt the specific page works fine, but the search page returns 0 items. No errors, just 0 items.This occurs on 2 different sites with 2 different spiders.

Is there something specific to search pages that has to be taken in account when using Scrapyrt?

Take a spider like this:

```py
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "minimal"
    
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
           "https://www.dungeondice.it/ricerca?controller=search&s=ticket+to+ride",
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)
            

    def parse(self, response):
        print("Found ", len(response.css("article")), " items")
        for article in response.css("article"):
            print("Item: ", article.css("img::attr(title)").get())
```

(I also set the Obey_robots = False)

I get 20 items back, if I run:

```
scrape crawl minimal
```

But I get 0 items back (no errors, just no results), if I run:

```
curl "http://localhost:9081/crawl.json?spider_name=minimal&url=https://www.dungeondice.it/ricerca?controller=search&s=ticket+to+ride"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put "return item" in the end of "process_item" in your pipeline.py:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ...
    return item
```

I found the same issue as you described, after I edit my codes, I solved it.
Hope this could help =)

Comment: I looked at my pipelines.py file and found already with a return item. Do I have to make a pipeline.py myself somewhere else? I'm pretty sure the problem lies with scrapyrt though, because the simple spider works.